# Not opening inventory when right clicking

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I've been trying to create a custom inventory and everything seems fine but in-game when I try to right-click the item that opens the inventory, the inventory doesn't open.

```
        Inventory playerInfoInv = plugin.getServer().createInventory(null, 27, ChatColor.GOLD + "Player Info");
        p.openInventory(playerInfoInv);
    }


    @EventHandler
    public void onInteract(PlayerInteractEvent e) {
        Player p = e.getPlayer();
        Material getItemInHand = e.getItem().getType();
        Action a = e.getAction();


        if (getItemInHand.equals(SKULL_ITEM)) {
            if (a.equals(Action.LEFT_CLICK_AIR))
            playerInfoInventory(p);
        }
    }
```

This is the skull item meta if it might impact this:

```
        //Player skull
        ItemStack pSkull = new ItemStack(SKULL_ITEM,1,(short) SkullType.PLAYER.ordinal());
        SkullMeta pMeta = (SkullMeta) pSkull.getItemMeta();
        pMeta.setOwner(p.getName());
        pMeta.setDisplayName(ChatColor.BLUE + "Player Info");
        ArrayList<String> pSkullLore = new ArrayList<String>();
        pSkullLore.add(ChatColor.WHITE + "Show Player Stats");
        pMeta.setLore(pSkullLore);
        pMeta.addItemFlags(ItemFlag.HIDE_ATTRIBUTES);
        pSkull.setItemMeta(pMeta);
        p.getInventory().setItem(0, pSkull);
```

Comment: You are checking if the player has left clicked in your code, also I wouldn't recommend using `.equals` for enums.

Comment: @DaCurse Ohhh lol.
What would you recommend on using then?

Comment: Just `==`, does changing the action fix your problem?

Comment: No it didn't I tried changing the inventory creation method to:

 
`public static Inventory playerInfoInventory = Bukkit.createInventory(null, 18, ChatColor.GOLD + "Player Info");
    static{
        playerInfoInventory.setItem(4, new ItemStack(SKULL_ITEM));
    }`

and it worked

Answer (score 1):

At first: e.getItem() can be null. So maybe you could get an NullPointer.

The second: ItemStack#getType() returns Material. And you are checking for SKULL_ITEM not Material.SKULL_ITEM (same mistake you made at initializing your variable pSkull).

The Third: Check if your Listener is Registered.